# Como agrupar registros por mês e ano, dentro de uma lista de objetos? ASP NET CORE

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp-net-core

Estou tentando agrupar os objetos de uma lista por mes ou ano, antes de retornar o mesmo.

estou tentando da seguinte maneira e não obtive sucesso.

```cs
foreach (var item in passList)
{
   pass_obj = new Pass_returnDTO();
   pass_obj.pass_date_time = item.pass_date_time.Date;
   pass_obj.qty_pass = Convert.ToInt32(item.qty_daily_pass);
   listRegistro.Add(pass_obj);
}

if (grouper == "ano")
{
  objReturn.registros.GroupBy( d => d.pass_date_time.Year);
  listPassReturn.Add(objReturn);
}                  
else if (grouper == "mes")
{
  objReturn.registros.GroupBy(d => d.pass_date_time.Month);
  listPassReturn.Add(objReturn);
}
```

Comment: Já conseguiu resolver? Caso não tenha resolvido, vc quer agrupar por ano e mês e ter a quantidade de registros por agrupamento? Seria tipo: 2019-09 - quantidade = 10, 2019-08 - quantidade = 20...

Comment: Olá @RaquelPinheiro, já consegui sim, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cs
//agrupando registros por ano
var lista = objReturn.register.GroupBy(d => d.pass_date_time.ToString("yyyy"))
           .Select(x => new { Year = x.Key, Sum = x.Sum(item => item.qty_pass) });

//agrupando registros por mês
var lista = objReturn.register.GroupBy(d => d.pass_date_time.ToString("yyyy/MM"))
           .Select(x => new { Month = x.Key, Sum = x.Sum(item => item.qty_pass) });
```